# grunt import database from shell

Tags: mysql, shell, gruntjs

I would like to use `grunt-shell` to import a database into a remote server.

This is what I have tried:

```
shell: {
            install_db: {
                options: {
                    stdout: true,
                    stderr: true
                },
                command: [
                    "ssh user@demo.server.it mysql < /Volumes/www/database/mydb.sql --database db_test -u root -p password",
                ].join("&&")
            }
        }
```

Inside my remote server I have user inside database called `root` and he has all priviligies.

When I run the frunt like

```
grunt shell
```

I retrieve this error:

```
Enter password: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But that user is correct I think.
I have also tried:

```
"ssh user@demo.server.it mysql < /Volumes/www/database/mydb.sql --database db_test -u root -p",
```

and

```
"ssh user@demo.server.it",
"sudo mysql < /Volumes/www/database/mydb.sql --database db_test -u root -p password",
```

Nothing it doesn't import my sql file inside my remote server.

I have already created that database.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend **resetting the root password**, this worked for me in Windows 7, MySQL 5.5.37

- Stop the MySQL process/service
- Disable the grant tables check:

In **Windows** go to

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini
```

In **Linux**

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

Under he section [mysqld] add skip-grant-tables

```
[mysqld]
skip-grant-tables
```

- Restart MySQL process/service
- Go to MySQL prompt, you need no user/password since you have disabled the grant tables check

  C:>mysql
- Execute the following commands, replace 'your_secret_password' accordingly

  UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_secret_password') WHERE User='root';
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
- Exit MySQL prompt
- Stop the MySQL process/service
- Enable the grant tables check: remove from my.ini or my.cnf the line

  skip-grant-tables
- Restart the MySQL process/service

Comment: I'm not using WIndows but OSX, and the password is OK is another the problem I think

Comment: try removing the space -uroot -pyour_password